Help recreating sound effects for a uni project
I am attempting to recreate this garp vs aokiji scene( 

 ) from one piece for a sound design assessment in uni. i have made a handful of the sounds already, mostly the ice related ones. however I'm stuck on how to make some of the effects, namely the explosion effects from garps punches, garp punching the big block of ice at 00:26, and garp grabbing aokiji at 00:43. the rest I have a decent idea on how to recreate if I haven't made them already. I am allowed to use other peoples samples for certain raw sounds (e.g I'm not gonna be expected to smash a plate if I want to use the sound of a plate smashing), but I can't use other peoples fully mixed sound effects, the final products sound effects must have all been created by me.
